# How to find palindromic numbers (Project Euler #4)?

Tags: function-construction, project-euler, palindrome

I'm trying to solve the [fourth Project Euler's problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4) with this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = Range[800, 999]; l1 = {}; x = 1; p = 1;
l = Subsets[a, {2}]; l8 = {};
While[x <= Length[l], AppendTo[l1, (l[[x]][[1]]*l[[x]][[2]])]; x++]
```

---

```
func[k_] := 
 StringReplace[ToString[Take[l1, {k, k}]], {"{" -> "", "}" -> ""}]

f1[y_] := StringTake[func[y], {1, 1}] == StringTake[func[y], {6, 6}]
f2[y_] := StringTake[func[y], {2, 2}] == StringTake[func[y], {5, 5}]
f3[y_] := StringTake[func[y], {3, 3}] == StringTake[func[y], {4, 4}]
f4[y_] := f1[y] || f2[y] || f3[y]
```

---

```
While[p <= Length[l1], 
 If[f4[p] == True, AppendTo[l8, l1[[p]]], AppendTo[l8, False]]; p++]
```

This is suposed to generate the multiples of (800*800), (800*801), (...*...), (999*999), I guess the problem is on the detached mid, I made that functions to check If the number in question is a [palindromic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome_number) but it gives me 701600 as a palindromic number. Something is wrong but I can't see where. Can you help me?

**EDIT:** Ok, it's solved, you can check [here](https://sites.google.com/site/legitimacyonimbecility/achievements/postagemsemtitulo-1), I've also made two plots on the distribution of the palindromic numbers. I just [did it again](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVrwzjtBHq0&feature=player_detailpage#t=85s) and used Fx's advice.

Comment: When you limit your search to six-digit numbers they will look like `abccba` and therefore must be multiples of 11, whence at least one of the factors is a multiple of 11. This can readily be exploited to speed up the solution by an order of magnitude :-). If you focus optimistically on the numbers of the form `9bccb9`, then both factors must be odd, further reducing the effort by 75%. Considering they must also exceed 900 and screening the results modulo 10, you can do this problem with pencil and paper in just a few minutes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logical operators in `f4` need to be `&&` (logical and), not `||` (logical or):

```
f4[y_] := f1[y] && f2[y] && f3[y]
```

Comment: Yep. I just probed with `1 == 1 || 1 == 1 || 1 == 0` and it gave me `True`.

Comment: Even with `f4[y_] := f1[y] && f2[y] && f3[y]`it still give me a number which is not palindromic, such as 701600.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira I kindly suggest you accept a more complete answer below, rather than mine :)

Comment: Yep, but your answer was more helpful to me because I've already had something done - yours was a fix on what I was doing. These guys answers are GREAT, indeed. But I couldn't implement or understand because I still don't know how to use Mathematica properly. Their answers are going to be VERY useful in the near future, because I'm reading : "Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction" from Leonid Schifrin.

Answer (score 10):

You can skip the whole string thing and use `IntegerDigits` to check if it is palindromic.  If I'm interpreting what you are doing right, you just can create `l8` as so:

```
l8 = l1 /. k_Integer /; Reverse[IntegerDigits[k]] != IntegerDigits[k] -> False
```

Or if you just want the palindromic ones by themselves:

```
Pick[l1, Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]] == IntegerDigits[#] & /@ l1]
```

Also,

```
l1 = Times @@@ l
```

is a bit nicer than a `While` loop.

Comment: Strings are generally a bit faster especially if it's a large integer, so I would go with your earlier comment (now removed) and use `StringReverse` along with `IntegerString`

Answer (score 10):

Very bruteforcing, but some beauty in it :)

```
NestWhileList[
   FindInstance[
      a b == Array[10^#&, 6, 0].{p,l,k,k,l,p} &&
      a b > (a b /. #[[1]])                   &&
      And@@ (100 <= # < 1000 & /@ {a,b})      &&
      And@@ (  0 <= # <= 9   & /@ {l,k,p}),
   {l,k,p,a,b}, Integers] &,
{{a->100,b->100}}, # != {} &]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
palindromicQ = Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]] === IntegerDigits[#] &;
threeDigitDivs = Intersection[Range[100, 999], Divisors[#]] &; 
Select[Range[999999, 10000, -1], 
    And[palindromicQ[#], 
       Intersection[threeDigitDivs[#], #/threeDigitDivs[#]] =!= {}] &, 1]
 (* {906 609} *)

Select[Range[999999, 10000, -1], 
And[palindromicQ[#], 
   Intersection[threeDigitDivs[#], #/threeDigitDivs[#]] =!= {}] &, 10]
(* {906609, 888888, 886688, 861168, 855558, 853358, 840048, 828828, 824428, 821128} *)
```

**Update:** As usual, `Pick` with appropriate selector array is much faster than `Select` to generate all  655 numbers:

```
 palPrdctsOf3DigitNums = With[{
 palindromes = Pick[Range[10000, 1000000],
   Boole[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]] == IntegerDigits[#]] & /@ 
    Range[10000, 1000000], 1], 
 threedigitDivisors = 
  Function[{p}, Intersection[Range[100, 999], Divisors[p]]]},
Pick[palindromes,
 Boole[
    Intersection[
      threedigitDivisors[#], #/threedigitDivisors[#]] =!= {}] &
  /@ palindromes, 1]]; // Timing 
(* {0.64, Null} *)
(* MMA V 8.0.4.0  MS Windows Vista 64-bit Intel Core Duo2 T9600 @ 2.8GHz with 8G memory *)

ListPlot[Tooltip /@ palPrdctsOf3DigitNums]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Yet another brute force enumeration:

```
 DeleteDuplicates@
  Pick[#, Boole[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]] == IntegerDigits[#]] & /@ #,1] &
  @(Times @@@ (Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 100, 999}, {j, i, 999}], 1])) // 
  Length // Timing
 (* {0.593, 655} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

There's something to be said about successive filtering; it's still brute force, but you can keep using finer filters at each stage:

```
pals = Cases[Range[800 800, 999 999], n_ /; ((# === StringReverse[#]) &[IntegerString[n]])];

c1 = Cases[pals, n_ /; Count[Divisors[n], d_ /; IntegerLength[d] == 3] >= 2];

Cases[c1, n_ /; n == Times @@ Take[Cases[Divisors[n], d_ /; IntegerLength[d] == 3], -2]]

{642246, 648846, 649946, 652256, 653356, 656656, 657756, 660066,
 661166, 663366, 672276, 675576, 678876, 689986, 693396, 723327,
 729927, 737737, 747747, 749947, 770077, 780087, 793397, 801108,
 802208, 804408, 807708, 809908, 819918, 821128, 824428, 840048,
 853358, 855558, 861168, 886688, 888888, 906609}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a succinct solution that finds the largest palindrome:

```
Outer[(#1 #2 // IntegerDigits // If[# == Reverse[#], FromDigits[#], 0] &) &,
  Range[100, 999], Range[100, 999]] // Max
```

I have ignored the fact that `Times` is `Orderless` in order to optimise for readability rather than speed.

Answer (score 7):

Might be easier to start with palindromes, then see which have appropriate factors. This will be fast as long as we are in a size range where Divisors[] is fast.

```
palproduct[n_] := Catch[Module[
   {mult = 10^n, mminus1 = 10^n - 1, mover10 = 10^(n - 1), j, pal, 
    divs},
   For[j = mminus1, j >= mover10, j--,
    pal = mult*j + FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[j]]];
    divs = 
     Select[Divisors[pal], 
      mminus1 >= # >= j && mminus1 >= pal/# >= mover10 &];
    If[divs =!= {}, Throw[{pal, First[divs], pal/First[divs]}]]
    ]
   ]]

Table[Timing[palproduct[m]], {m, 2, 9}]

(*
{{0.01500000000010004, {9009, 91, 99}}, {0., {906609, 913, 
   993}}, {0., {99000099, 9901, 
   9999}}, {0.04699999999979809, {9966006699, 99681, 
   99979}}, {0.2810000000001764, {999000000999, 999001, 
   999999}}, {1.90300000000002, {99956644665999, 9997647, 
   9998017}}, {6.286999999999807, {9999000000009999, 99990001, 
   99999999}}, {86.5490000000002, {999900665566009999, 999920317, 
   999980347}}}
*)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a report on an upgrade in later versions. Things changed for the best with regards to this question. Since `V10.3` we have [`PalindromeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PalindromeQ.html.en).

We start by considering

```
a = Range[800, 999];
```

and then we create `(800*800), (800*801),...,(999*999)` like so:

```
data = Union @@ Outer[Times, a, a];
```

We run

```
Grid@Partition[MatrixForm /@ Select[data, PalindromeQ], 7]
```

> [image: gridprime]

And if we just want the largest one, following the statement of the problem,

```
Last@Select[data, PalindromeQ]
```

> [image: last]

Answer (score 3):

A fairly straightforward solution employing string manipulation (similar to IntegerDigits):

```
Last[
Select[
        Union[Flatten[Table[i*j, {i, 100, 999}, {j, 100, 999}]]], 
       # === ToExpression[StringReverse[ToString[#]]] &]]
```

Answer (score 3):

A fast method:

```
   Intersection[
       1000 # + FromDigits@Reverse@IntegerDigits[#] & /@ Range[100, 999], 
       Join @@ Outer[Times,  Range[100, 999], Range[110, 990, 11]]] // 
      Max // Timing
```

or

```
ok[n_] := 
  MemberQ[IntegerLength[
    Table[#[[{i, -i}]], {i, 2, Length[#]/2}] &[Divisors[n]]], {3, 3}];
Select[Flatten@
    Table[100001 i + 10010 j + 1100 k, {i, 9}, {j, 0, 9}, {k, 0, 9}], ok] // Max // Timing
```